# OAuth2 with Hash query string, Imgur API

Tags: oauth-2.0, imgur

I'm updating my desktop app, an Imgur client, for the upcoming deprecation of code/pin auth methods, by using a local web server to catch the redirect_url from the browser after the user authorizes access to the app. So I launch the URL in the browser, the user accepts, then Imgur redirects to

> http://localhost:7710/myapp?state=auth#access_token=....&expires_in=
>   etc

but the browser cuts the URL at # so all the variables are missing, and my app only receives "state=auth"

from Imgur's API docs:

> The response_type Parameter token: This authorization flow will
>   directly return the access_token and refresh_token via the redirect
>   URL you specified during registration, in the form of hash query
>   string parameters. Example:
>   http://example.com#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
>
> The code and pin response types have been deprecated and will soon no
>   longer be supported.
>
> Imgur returns an access token to your application if the user grants
>   your application the permissions it requested. The access token is
>   returned to your application in the fragment as part of the
>   access_token parameter. Since a fragment (the part of the URL after
>   the #) is not sent to the server, client side javascript must parse
>   the fragment and extract the value of the access_token parameter.

Clearly they haven't thought this through for desktop applications, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Imgur stuff looks non standard, since response_type=token is a basic version of the implicit flow, which used to be the solution for single page pps.

These days all UI based flows should use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) and response_type=code.

Since your app is acting as a (loopback) web server it will not receive the hash fragment parameters, which are only available to JavaScript code running in a browser.

One option that would enable you to get the full URL would be to login via the system browser and to use a [Private URI Scheme](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/) to call back to the app.

The above link is a visual blog post to explain how this works, in case it is of interest.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using app protocols, it seems like more trouble + differences between the versions of Windows

Comment: Yep - it can be quite a bit of work. If I were you I would not rush to change your code to the wrong / implicit flow. I would start by getting in touch with Imgur. Updating to correct flows is in their interests and will benefit multiple current and future customers.